# Command for moving subfolders with files, with keeping the original structure

Tags: linux, shell

I have a **parent/** folder with a couple of subfolders in it. Structure:

```
/parent/
    /subfolder_1/
        - file_1.txt
        - file_2.txt
    /subfolder_2/
        - file_3.txt
        - file_4.txt
```

Now, I need to recursively **move** the contents of **parent/** folder to the empty **parent_tmp/** directory. Thing is, I need to keep the original folder structure in **parent/**.

**Expected outcome after moving:**

```
    /parent/
        /subfolder_1/
            (empty)
        /subfolder_2/
            (empty)


    /parent_tmp/
        /subfolder_1/
            - file_1.txt
            - file_2.txt
        /subfolder_2/
            - file_3.txt
            - file_4.txt
```

Normally, I would simply do

```
mv parent/* parent_tmp
```

but this will, of course, move the subfolders permanently.

Is there a way to adjust the `mv` command to keep the original structure of the source directory?

**Note:**

I realize that I can e.g. copy **parent/** to **parent_tmp**, and then remove the files in **parent/** subfolders. This is plan B to me.

Answer (score 2):

You could copy the files

```
cp -r parent/* parent_tmp/
```

or create hard links (should be a lot faster for big files)

```
cp -l -r parent/* parent_tmp/
```

and then delete the original files

```
find parent -type f -delete
```

while keeping the directory structure.

Comment: This solution takes a lot of disk space if the directory contains large files. A better solution would be to copy just the directories and then move all files.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `find` from parent of `parent` and `parent_tmp` directoroies:

```
find parent -type f -exec bash -c 'mkdir -p "parent_tmp/${1%/*}" && 
      mv "$1" "parent_tmp/${1%/*}"' - {} \;
```

Answer (score 1):

Zip the content of the parent folder and Unzip it in the target folder.

Answer (score 1):

**Quick and Dirty:**

I don't think you'll find a tool or option in the mv command to do what you want, but you should be able to achieve the desired goal by using find:

```
cd parent && while read file ; do dirname="$(dirname "$file")" ; mkdir -p ../parent_tmp/"$dirname"/; mv "$file" "../parent_tmp/"${file#}"" ; done < <( find . -type f ) && cd -
```

**Function**

If you use this a lot then you can add the above to your ~/.basrc like so (append to the end of the file):

```
alias mvkp=moveandkeep

moveandkeep() {

    cd "$1"
    while read file ;
    do dirname="$(dirname "$file")" ;
        mkdir -p "$2"/"${dirname#}";
        mv "$file" ""$2"/"${file#}"";
    done < <(find . -type f)
    cd -

}
```

Now you could simply do the following: (Full path to directories required)

```
mvkp /home/user/parent /home/user/parent_tmp
```

Comment: What is "source" here? Quote all your variables to accomodate directories with whitespace. Good ideas in there.